A Phase Retieval Problem for L2 functions with exponentially decreasing Fourier transform
Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\hat{f} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^{2 |\xi|}d\xi) $, where $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$. I am trying to work out whether the additional assumption
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\overline{f(-x)} \text{ for all } x\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
\hat{f}(x)=\overline{\hat{f}(-x)} \text{ for all } x\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}  implies that the Pauli problem for $f$ is uniqe. Which means that for any $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\hat{g} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^{2 |\xi|}d\xi)$, the condition
\begin{align*}
|g|=|f| \text{ and } |\hat{g}|=|\hat{f}|
\end{align*}
implies that $g$ is a unimodular multiple of $f$, i.e. there exists an $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|\alpha|=1$ and $f=\alpha g$.
The reason why I think this might be  true is that it is true if we replace the property $\hat{f} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^{2 |\xi|}d\xi)$ by the stronger property that $\hat{f}$ has compact support. In that case, by the Paley-Wiener theorem, $f$ extends to an entire function. But in our case, $f$ only extends to a holomorphic function on the horizontal strip $\{ |\text{Im} z| <1\}$ and I am not sure how to use that. Any help would be appreciated.
